# Grouped barplot from two categorial variables

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have two categorial variables: `education.type` and `work.type`.

```
education.type = c(1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1)
work.type = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1)
```

1 = "technical"
2 = "non-technical"

I would like to have a grouped barplot that looks as follows:

[image]

Thanks for response

Comment: Please demonstrate what you've tried and where you got stuck

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
education.type=c(1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1)
work.type=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1)
tt =table(education.type, work.type)
tt
              work.type
education.type 1 2
             1 4 3
             2 4 2
barplot (tt,beside=TRUE)
```

The tt table is not as desired, hence the barplot is wrong.
So I tried cbind.

```
cc = cbind(education.type, work.type)
cc
      education.type work.type
 [1,]              1         1
 [2,]              1         2
 [3,]              2         1
 [4,]              1         2
 [5,]              2         1
 [6,]              2         2
 [7,]              1         1
 [8,]              1         2
 [9,]              2         1
[10,]              2         2
[11,]              1         1
[12,]              2         1
[13,]              1         1
```

The barplot gives a bar for each entry

Answer (score 0):

```
education.type = c(1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1)
work.type = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1)

te = sum(education.type == 1)
nte = sum(education.type == 2)

tw = sum(work.type == 1)
ntw = sum(work.type == 2)

education = rbind(te, nte)
work = rbind(tw, ntw)

df = as.data.frame(cbind(education, work))
rownames(df) = c("technical", "nontechnical")
colnames(df) = c("education", "work")
df$x = rownames(df)

library(reshape2)
mlt = melt(df, id.vars = "x")
mlt

ggplot(data=mlt, aes(x=x, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]